# Windows 10 UI freezes because of GPU driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, bsod, intel-graphics

I've got a new laptop 3-4 weeks ago and it used to work fine until a week ago I started to get multiple BSOD with different error codes and just interface freezes when everything is stuck and I have nothing to do but hard reload.

I've performed a clean reinstall of windows but it didn't solve the issue.

I've checked RAM with Windows Memory Diagnostic tool and it's all fine.

I've been struggling with it for several days until I've found multiple similar issues on the web and people say that it might be an issue with integrated intel GPU driver with a high probability. So I installed the latest driver version (27.20.100.9466) available for my GPU (Intel® HD Graphics 630) and it was ok for several hours (which surprised me a lot because before this I got my laptop stuck every 5-10 minutes) but then I got this issue again.

I've tried a clean install of GPU driver (Uninstall device from device manager and install it from scratch) and it had been working fine for the whole day until I got the issue again today in the evening.

So since clean driver reinstall solves the issue for some period of time my assumption that it's really related to Intel GPU.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**My configuration**:

- Intel Core i7-10750H
- 32 GB RAM
- Intel® HD Graphics 630 (driver version 27.20.100.9466)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti (driver version 466.11)
- Windows 10 PRO (20H2, OS Build 19042.928)

**NOTE**:
I have got a second similar laptop with a similar configuration and it works like a charm. It has a 2004 windows build version so I thought that it might be some version conflict between windows 20H2 and GPU driver, so I tried to roll back the broken laptop to the 2004 windows version but it didn't work out.

All this makes me think that the broken laptop has a hardware issue rather than a software/driver issue. Because when you perform clean windows reinstall, clean driver reinstall and it still doesn't work and you have the same laptop which just works, so seems like it's really some bad hardware. Really wanna be wrong with this assumption.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: New machine. Check for legacy or non-compliant software and then contact the manufacturer for warranty service.

Comment: Try to find useful errors in the Event Viewer. If you have recent `.dmp` files in `C:\Windows\Minidump`, you could zip up a couple and post them online for us.

Comment: I see 10 such critical errors in the Event Viewer

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          4/27/2021 19:24:21
Event ID:      41
Task Category: (63)
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      (70368744177664),(2)
User:          SYSTEM
Description:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

Comment: And this is a dump file description:
On Mon 4/26/2021 22:17:30 your computer crashed or a problem was reported
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\042621-7921-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x3F5E40) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000096, 0xFFFFF8065D762711, 0x0, 0x0)
Error: KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

Comment: Open the minidump file with an application called WhoCrashed, it'll help pin-point the driver which caused the kernel to fall over.

Comment: The info I attached above is from WhoCrashed actually.

Comment: I've found another dump file which says:
crash dump file: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP
This was probably caused by the following module: ntkrnlmp.exe (nt!HvlPerformEndOfInterrupt+0x4DEE) ;

And seems like ntkrnlmp.exe is really connected with GPU (https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fixed-ntkrnlmp-exe-blue-screen-error/)